# JSON Java - is it possible to loop through multiple layers of JSON at once in search of a specific value?

Tags: java, json

Imagine I have a much bigger version of this:

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "age": 10,
  "number": 254,
  "spezial": [{
      "name": "vip",
      "age": 12,
      "number": 134
  }, {
      "name": "b",
      "age": 56,
      "number": 934
  }]
}
```

Now all I want is something like `json.containsValue("vip")` which returns either true if there is a value "vip" somewere, or false if there isn't.
I really don't want to loop through each sub Array individually, I would need ten lines of code just to test for a duplicate...
Thanks for thinking about my problem

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: The value can be mapped to any key?

Comment: I mean you will need to check all the elements to confirm that vip doesn't exist. There's nothing performance wise you can do.

Comment: @BenArnao I don't think the question is about performance.

Comment: @shmosel json-simple-1.1.1   And yes, any, doesn't matter

Comment: What about array values? E.g. `[1, {"a": 2}, "vip"]`

Comment: @shmosel Everything in the file is generated by my programm, so there really shouldn't be something looking like this.. But even if there is, I don't mind, if the word is in there somewere, give me my true.

Comment: But not as a key...

Comment: @shmosel this word will never be a key, but I'm sorry you're right, I'm actually only looking for it as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will recursively search all object and array values for a given string:

```
static boolean findValue(Object node, String value) {
    if (node instanceof String) {
        return node.equals(value);
    }
    else if (node instanceof JSONArray) {
        for (Object obj : (JSONArray)node) {
            if (findValue(obj, value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (node instanceof JSONObject) {
        for (Object obj : ((JSONObject)node).values()) {
            if (findValue(obj, value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sample use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Object json = new JSONParser().parse(
            "{" +
            "  \"name\": \"a\"," +
            "  \"age\": 10," +
            "  \"number\": 254," +
            "  \"spezial\": [{" +
            "      \"name\": \"vip\"," +
            "      \"age\": 12," +
            "      \"number\": 134" +
            "  }, {" +
            "      \"name\": \"b\"," +
            "      \"age\": 56," +
            "      \"number\": 934" +
            "  }]" +
            "}");
    System.out.println(findValue(json, "vip"));
    System.out.println(findValue(json, "foo"));
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll take a while to fully test this.. But it looks just perfect, thanks a lot! 'instanceof', 'findValue()', sounds great, I'll read more about them in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

If the value is just a String and provided you only want a boolean return value , why don`t you try String.contains(": \"vip\" ")?

Comment: That's assuming there's exactly one space after the colon. Also, it's not clear whether array values should count too.

Comment: The JSON-File is quite huge, I learned that it's bad practice to make gigantic strings, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: @harlekintiger How are you going to parse JSON without a string?

Comment: we can get rid of spaces and then check in that case

Comment: It does not matter if you are not going to process the information. 
For your problem , I assume all you want is a Boolean value.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code, it should work

```
if(JSON.stringify(dataObject).indexOf('"vip"') != -1){
    return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```

Note: dataObject - is your JSON object.

Put this in a separate function to use this as util.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Actually this can be faster than the other recursive answers. But need to handle special cases where a key itself is named as the search term. Also I am not sure if '"vip"' is valid in java. You may have to escape the double quotes like \"vip\"

Comment: this is javascript.. If you got to do this in Java, you can use JSON parser (Jackson - import this is in your pom.xml or use jar). Create a java object pertaining to your json.. CustomObject ob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(yourjsonInStringFormat, CustomObject .class); Then you can iterate through the list of "spezial" objects.